# SQL DMV max_elapsed_time Timestamp of longest elapsed query

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I know this is a long shot, as googling hasn't revealed any answers close to what I'm looking for - the same searching has also not yet proved that it can't be done either.

Basically I would like to know if MSSQL 2008 R2 captures the timestamp of the query execution instance that is being reported as 'max_elapsed_time' (or max_worker_time etc...) in the results that are returned from sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

I do not have the depth of knowledge to know where to start digging to find out if this information is stored\available (have already spend +5 hours sifting through the labyrinth of statistical functions and views - very interesting space to get lost in).

Out of interest (as I am starting to look at Migrating to SQL 2016 - two year plan) this looks to be possible to setup manually with a well formed extended event?